# Others can update an Opportunity Owner to a particular user, but he can't update it to himself?

Tags: opportunity

My org just switched to Lightning and a user says he can not set himself as the Owner of an Opportunity. He can set the owner to someone else (a user with a standard sales profile) but then he can't switch it back to himself. Others can set the owner to him as well.

When he tries to set the user to himself from a different owner, it says -

"You don’t have permission to take that action on this record or related records. For help, contact your Salesforce admin."

This person's profile has all the same read/write permissions on Opportunities as the other user's profile. I don't know what I should be looking into here. Is there a different restriction for assigning something to yourself or is it just something permission related I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

Transferring ownership of a record requires "Full" permission, not just "Write" permission. You have "Full" permission if you're the owner of the record, or a manager in the role hierarchy of the user that owns the record, or a user with Modify All Data. So, if you own the opportunity, you can freely give it to someone else, but you may not be able to take it back. The new owner could give it back to them, or a system administrator could, or someone in management. You can read more in [Transferring Records](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=data_about_transfer.htm). Here's an applicable quote from the documentation:

> To transfer ownership of any single record in an organization that does not use territory management, a user must have the appropriate “Edit” permission and either own the record or be above the owner in the role hierarchy.
>   For example, to transfer ownership of an account, a user must have “Read” and “Edit” access to the account. Additionally, the new owner of the record must have at least “Read” permission on accounts.